# Cannot communicate between network switches

Tags: windows, networking, ethernet, dhcp, switch

I have quite a strange predicament and would appreciate any help.

First of all, I have a home router with fast internet and we are "sharing" this internet to our business 0.7 miles down using a Tycon EZBridge Lite wifi bridge.

On the business end, I have a router hooked up to the receiver bridge and have it set to AP mode. Essentially this creates one big network from home to the business site.

Anyhow, on the remote site we have two POS systems. One of them is the server (192.168.1.2 - static) and the other is the client (dynamic). Client POS can detect server and work fine, both having a direct Ethernet line to the AP router.

Works just as well when the server is connected to an unmanaged switch connected to the router.

Where the problem occurs is when the client is connected to an unmanaged switch connected to the AP router, and the server is connected to a different switch connected to the same router. Somehow, in this scenario the client cannot detect the server POS. Both still have internet access and seem to be connected to DHCP, and can even ping each other through Windows CMD. However, the POS software cannot detect the server when both are connected this way.

Is this a problem specific to the software (POS), or it is related to the networking? Any help possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to disable DHCP on the POS server? If so, you should do that. It's a bad idea to have two conflicting DHCP servers on one network - your main router (presumably at your home) is the one that should be assigning IPs.

Comment: @SamForbis I believe there is only one DHCP server which is the one at home. The router at the business site is set to AP mode so it should just be redirecting clients... also sorry about the text I meant that the client is dynamic ip using dhcp it itself is not a dhcp server.

Comment: Could you post the network setup (ip addresses, gateways etc) of each device?

Comment: @jvda I know the server is 192.168.1.2, subnet 255.255.255.0, DNS 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1, gateway 192.168.1.1

Comment: Client has the same subnet and DNS but has a dynamic 192.168.1.xxx IP.